# Problems when trying to create an event

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an event but I get the error below:

[image]

And my query:

```
CREATE EVENT insert_count
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 50 SECOND
COMMENT 'bla bla bla bla bla bla.'
DO BEGIN
INSERT INTO teste (nome, conectado, desconectado)
SELECT parceiro.nomeP AS 'Parceiro', 
SUM(di.connectedOr = 'true') AS 'ClientesConectados', 
SUM(di.connectedOr = 'false') AS 'ClientesDesconectados'
FROM vpn AS di
JOIN parceiro
ON parceiro.codParceiro = di.idpartner
WHERE di.comName REGEXP 'skytef-'
GROUP BY di.idpartner
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be your `SUM`s. I think they should look like this: `SUM(IF(di.connectedOr = 'true', 1, 0))`

Comment: The `1, 0` would be 'ClientesConectados' and 'ClientesDesconectados'?

Comment: Did not work. The column name changed to `SUM(IF(di.connectedOr = 'true', 1, 0))`

Comment: Does the insert work outside of the event? I've never used events. So I'm not sure about the syntax for creating one.

Comment: Actually, I just Googled it. It looks like you may just need to remove the words `BEGIN` and `END`